# ios app crashes on fill cell with image literal only on ios 9 not clear crash log

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have an e-commerce application that views a list of products for the user ,and after the latest update i have been receiving a lot of crashes from fabric crashlytics on ios 9 only , that i couldn't replicate in any way while testing.

relevant crash log

> 0  libswiftUIKit.dylib            0x10166f218 _TToFE5UIKitCSo7UIImagecfT24imageLiteralResourceNameSS_S0_ + 224
>
> 1  libswiftUIKit.dylib            0x10166f040
>   _TFE5UIKitCSo7UIImageCfT24imageLiteralResourceNameSS_S0_ + 96
>
> 2  "AppName"                       0x1000e7788 specialized
>   ItemsSubCategoriesCell.fill(withInfo : ItemsSubCategory) -> ()
>   (ItemsSubCategoriesCell.swift:39)
>
> 3  "AppName"                        0x1000b9b88 specialized
>   ItemsSubCategoriesViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt :
>   IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (ItemsSubCategoriesViewController.swift)
>
> 4  "AppName"                        0x1000b91c4 @objc
>   ItemsSubCategoriesViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt :
>   IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (ItemsSubCategoriesViewController.swift)

relevant block of code

```
func fill(withInfo info: ItemsSubCategory) {

    backgroundColor = info.primaryColor
    numberOfItemsLabel.text = "\(info.items.count)"
    discloseIndicatorImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Disclosure Indicator").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    discloseIndicatorImageView.tintColor = info.darkBackground ? UIColor.white : UIColor.gray

    if let imageURLString = info.photoFile?.url {
        sectionImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageURLString)!)
    }
}
```

problem is , i tried to replicate this crash on multiple test mobiles, and i would appreciate any pointers to the possible reason for the crash

**Edit:**
I tried changing the image name to remove spaces , and also tried image with resource name instead of using #imageliteral , and tried to test it locally and on testflight with no crashes, pushed to production and the crashes are back.

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with your image literal. Maybe try having your image/resource names without spaces? `disclosure-indicator`

Comment: thank you, will try , but also i cannot confirm if it will fix the issue since i cannot replicate the bug on testing environment

Comment: The problem is that image literal force unwraps the image. If the image can't be loaded, the app crashes. Question is why the image can't be loaded. I even thought the AppStore does some bad optimisation, but our app also crashes in the Fabric build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue

```
    backgroundColor = info.primaryColor
    numberOfItemsLabel.text = "\(info.items.count)"
    let tempImage = UIImage(named: "DisclosureIndicator")
    discloseIndicatorImageView.image = tempImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    discloseIndicatorImageView.tintColor = info.darkBackground ? UIColor.white : UIColor.gray
```

I just created a tempImage UIIMage and then assigned it